# Document inside document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert multiple objects in one field. Here is the example.

I have a collection of `Questions` whose fields are `Q_ID`, `Q_Question` and `Q_ANS`.

Now, the user posts a question and it goes into:

- Q_ID:1
- Q_Question:'this is question'

Now, the other users will post answers.

How can I insert multiple answers, one by one, in `Q_ANS`? I tried

```
db.Questions.update({ans:'this is ans'},{$set:{Q_ID:1}})
```

but it just replaced the previous answer. I want to insert all answers in `Q_ANS` one by one as they were posted.

Comment: I think Q_ANS must be an array, you can use $push

Answer (score 2):

You should use $addToSet

```
db.Questions.update({ans:'this is ans'},{$addToSet:{Q_ID:1}})
```

If the documents are identicall this will update it.

If you want to add and do not care about duplicates, yu can use $push

```
db.Questions.update({ans:'this is ans'},{$push:{Q_ID:1}})
```

Edit:

This links can help you a bit

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: How about you actually write some code in your response that provides a solution to the problem that was asked. If you want some cred here then that is what you do.

Comment: @NeilLunn I dont even know which language the question owner is using, so how can I write some code. Besides, if he copy what I write and paste it on the mongo console, it will work ;)

Comment: this is not the exact answer but the links you gave helped me +1

Comment: Im glad that you find them useful. The mongodb documentation is always very helpful